# How to append a new row with copied data from another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a basic outline of copying data from one spreadsheet and pasting it into another one. However I need it to append rows rather than re-write one I know currently the way it is written I'm telling it where to write but I need help.

I'm also having trouble getting the data to move in the same format. The information it grabs is organized one row on top of another but I want to paste it as one row that is longer.

```
function copyPaste(sourceLink, sourceSheet, sourceRange, destiLink, destiSheet, destiRange) {

  //Source link
  var ssRaw = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sourceLink);
  var sheetRaw = ssRaw.getSheetByName(sourceSheet);
  var range = sheetRaw.getRange(sourceRange);
  var data = range.getValues();

  //Destination 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(destiLink);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(destiSheet);

  //Transfer to destination range
  sheet.getRange(destiRange).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(destiRange).setValues(data);  
}


function run() {
  copyPaste('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cXFr_mkS_Hheicg1oNTZzrk65NeqYwiDpsi1TygcYI/edit#gid=1155920417',
'Invoice Calculator',
'J6:J9',
'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cXFr_mkS_Hheicg1oNTZzrk65NeqYwiDpsi1TygcYI/edit#gid=1810062534',
'Employee Pay Tracker',
'C3:C6')
}
```

I have tried adding the `appendRow` in different places but I'm not sure if I did it right.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I'm also having trouble getting the data to move in the same format. The information it grabs is organized one row on top of another but I want to paste it as one row that is longer.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71288337/7215091

Comment: The only way to move formats is by using copyTo() or moveTo() from Class Range.  setValues() only moves the values.  And copyTo and moveTo only work inside of the same Spreadsheet.  You can start by copying the source sheet to the destination spreadsheet temporarily and the delete it at the end.